# Structured data disappeared from google console

Tags: google-search-console, microdata, statistics

I have two websites which are twin, both using `schema.org` microdata format to construct structured data.

Both websites had their data visible in google webmaster console. But i noticed a sudden drop in one of the website's statistics. Here is an screenshot:

[image: Drop in number of identified items]

As you can see there is a huge drop in the number of identified markups. I didn't modify the HTML files or remove anything, i was actually posting more contents these days. However, everything is fine in the twin website.

Here is an screenshot from the twin's search console:

[image]

As you can see the numbers are growing each day, even when the twin has less posts and hasn't been updated in months.

What's happening here? I've checked my HTML markups and i can still see the structure is intact.

**PS** I have to mention the twin website is in Russian, while this site is in English, so i don't think it would be a matter of duplicated content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your data, it appears to fall inline with the console update posted in your screen shot.  It looks like the data dipped at the same time google did a console update.  May want to investigate and see if that data anomaly is associated to your dip as it seems very coincidental that the graph was effected around the same time the console had an update which shows your dip.

Comment: Thank you. This is the twin website i asked another question about the other day (which you posted an answer). But as you see in the image, i already checked the provided link. I don't understand why a twin website inheriting the exact theme and code and hosted on the same host provider should be so different than the other one.